# Plot data as 3d function from text

Tags: python

I have a text file in the following format.

```
1 10 3
1  9 2
1  4 5
2 10 2  
2  6 5
3  4 3  
3  5 4
3  8 1
```

The first column represents the players. There are 3 coaches. The second column represents players. There are 10 players in total. The third column represents the grade (min can be 1 max can be 5) given to each player by the different coaches. Notice that not all the players have been rated and only some players have been rated. I basically want to plot this as a 3d function in python for the data I have.

I was wondering what is the best approach to do this?

My approach

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open("test.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()

data = data.split('\n')

x = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
y = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]
z = [row.split(' ')[2] for row in data]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

My error

```
  File "solution.py", line 10, in <module>
    y = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: At a guess, you have an empty line in your data file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split works on whitepace by default. Also performing split again for every variable when a single split yields all 3 values is wasteful, and will net you a low grade. And, of course, if some player have not been rated you need to check that before extracting the grade:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

with open("test.txt") as f:
    for row in f:
        coordinate = row.split()
        if len(coordinate) < 3: # an empty line or don't have a grade
            continue

        ax.scatter(*coordinate, c='r', marker='o')

plt.show()
```

You can also accumulate x, y and z in 3 lists and plot scatter with one call, but I think that plotting a dot for every row is less code = more elegant.